# Selenium IDE Flow Control (gotoif) - "Error: Specified label "labelName" is not found"

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am creating a test and before the test tests something, the language of the website has to be changed. After the gotoif which checks if the language isEnglish I want to jump to the label "labelChangeLanguage", but I always get the excpetion that it couldn't be found. But well, it's there.

Here the screenshot of the failing selenium test:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens after it's supposed to go to the label? It appears that the test is stuck in a loop, constantly checking and going back to that gotoif command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two gotoif conditional statements where you only need one.  Just use the first one and then a gotoLabel for the next line like this:

gotoIf | '${isEnglish}'== 'true' | changeLanguage
goto | done
label | labelChangeLanguage

goto | done
label | done

The way it works, it will evaluage ${isEnglish}.  If that's true it will jump to the label changeLanguage, if not, it immediately goes to the next line, which will jump to your done label.  Note that I changed the label to remove the word label in the name for readability.